# Smooth Image Change Animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uikit, uiviewanimation

**I change the background image when scrolling occurs in ScrollView. But it's not smooth and the freezes change the image. How can I solve this problem?**

*Below are the functions I created and called the animation.*

```
private func transitionForBackgroundImage(with pageIndex: Int) {
    UIView.transition(
        with: self.backgroundImageView,
        duration: 1.0,
        options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
        animations: {
            self.backgroundImageView.image = self.models[pageIndex].backgroundImage
        },
        completion: nil)
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageIndex = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x/scrollView.frame.size.width)
    updatePageControlUI(currentPageIndex: pageIndex)
    transitionForBackgroundImage(with: pageIndex)
}
```

Comment: It gets called multiple times when you scroll.

Comment: Where should I call? When scrolling, the animation should start.

Comment: If that's what you want that is ok. But you should escape from the method if you already changed the image. Something like `if (self.backgroundImageView.image == self.models[pageIndex].backgroundImage) { return }` before the animation.

Comment: thanks for answer!!! I have one more question. ** Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ProtocolOrientedThemes.ViewController: 0x7fafc6436100>. ** Comes this warning. What is it and how is it resolved?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice before. You are using wrong animation. Use `UIview.animate` instead of `UIView.transition`.